# Cannot revoke Android inapp subscription

Tags: android, google-api, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

For testing purposes I am trying to revoke inapp subscription for Android app. I am using standard API call defined at https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/revoke and it responds with no errors. However, after calling for get API I am getting response like:

```
{
 "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
 "startTimeMillis": "1418380314678",
 "expiryTimeMillis": "1421058696393",
 "autoRenewing": true
}
```

So, nothing changed and even subscription I am trying to revoke is still active when I am getting complete list of subscriptions.
The strangest thing is the code I am running to revoke has worked two weeks ago. What I have missed with Android subscriptions?

Comment: Can you add more information about the API request / how you authenticated etc?

Comment: Authenticated using refresh_token. API request using defined on the Google API docs: POST https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/packageName/purchases/subscriptions/subscriptionId/tokens/token:revoke   Response is according to the docs with empty body and HTTP code 200. However subscription is still shown as active.

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question? @Vasyl

Comment: Actually no. It seems like APi is still being changed, cause for now call is performed with error response but subscriptions are revoked for the app.