# Does revoking google play subscription terminates it?

Tags: android, google-api, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

There is a similar question but without answer - [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656879/cannot-revoke-android-inapp-subscription)
I post another one with more details describing the matter.

According to documentation calling [REVOKE](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/revoke) through google play android api:

> Refunds and immediately revokes a user's subscription purchase. Access to the subscription will be terminated immediately and it will stop recurring.

After calling [REVOKE](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/revoke) the only change in the response to [GET](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get) is that the autoRenewing field returns false.

EDIT: It does show CANCELED (the info in Google Play app got refreshed after switching to other account and back again), **but below question is still valid.**
<s>Also Google Play application is still showing the subscription with status SUBSCRIBED.</s>

Does it mean that the documentation is not precise and calling [REVOKE](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/revoke) is equal to calling [CANCEL](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/cancel) followed by [REFUND](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/refund) - meaning the subscription is still valid until it expires?

The results above were obtained during Alpha testing - so called [TEST PURCHASES](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html)

Comment: Test Purchases do no support Refund() or Revoke() methods [source](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#testing-purchases).
But I have the same question (and would hate to have to test it with my real account) what response can I expect from [the server api - subscription get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get)